# Trying to clone Repo but getting this weird RSA message

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, rsa, ssh-keys, git-clone

I've spent about an hour now trying to figure out this issue, and have tried several different things on Stack Overflow but I've hit a wall each time.

I just got started using Ubuntu and was trying to clone my repo using SSH, but when did that, the message that returned in my terminal was:

> Cloning into 'xManualFindx'... Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I'm not sure what they are referring to by "RSA host key" and I don't recall ever creating a public key for this repo.  I usually work in Windows, so I'm not sure if there's a step I'm missing or if I just forgot something.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

to check for any existing keys type   ls ~/.ssh

```html
ls ~/.ssh
```

If you are cloning a repository through ssh  your git bash/terminal
will check for any pre-existing keys in  the ~/.ssh/ directory   and  your terminal tries to make connection with github account for key matching  (stored in SSH & GPG keys)

if the keys donot match you get the error message 'permission denied'.
for now  you  want to just clone the repository use https protocol

you can learn more about cloning via ssh [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to do HTTPS. I also, did ran "ls ~/.ssh" into my terminal and it gave back "known_host".  Do you by chance know what that means?

Comment: it means you or someone who has used that machine has made a key earlier and the ssh-agent added one of the public key into that known_host file
or you can  just move contents of .ssh folder to somewhere and perform the ssh-key generation steps

Comment: Oh nice!! Thank you for the input! :)